# Konva - Change offset position after zoom and rotation

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I'm trying to implement a rotation and zoom feature with a slider. I need an image to always rotate from the center of the viewport. The main idea is changing the position and offset of the stage after drag event. Here's what I've tried

```
const width = window.innerWidth
const height = window.innerHeight

// scale is temp
let stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'canvas',
  width,
  height,
  draggable: true,
  offset: {
    x: width / 2,
    y: height / 2
  },
  x: width / 2,
  y: height / 2
})

let mapLayer = new Konva.Layer()
let imageObj = new Image()

imageObj.onload = function () {
  let map = new Konva.Image({
    image: imageObj,
    prevX: 0,
    prevY: 0
  })

  layer.add(map)
  stage.add(mapLayer)

  stage.on('dragstart', () => {
    map.prevX = map.getAbsolutePosition().x
    map.prevY = map.getAbsolutePosition().y
  })

  stage.on('dragend', () => {
    let curX = map.getAbsolutePosition().x
    let curY = map.getAbsolutePosition().y
    let deltaX = Math.abs(map.prevX - curX)
    let deltaY = Math.abs(map.prevY - curY)

    if (curX > map.prevX) {
      stage.offsetX(stage.offsetX() - deltaX)
      stage.x(stage.x() - deltaX)
    } else {
      stage.offsetX(stage.offsetX() + deltaX)
      stage.x(stage.x() + deltaX)
    }

    if (curY > map.prevY) {
      stage.offsetY(stage.offsetY() - deltaY)
      stage.y(stage.y() - deltaY)
    } else {
      stage.offsetY(stage.offsetY() + deltaY)
      stage.y(stage.y() + deltaY)
    }

    stage.draw()
  })
}
```

(if you want a full source code, [clone it from here](https://github.com/Namchee/lame-map) and run `yarn run dev` from terminal, the app lives on `localhost:3000`

It works fine when the image is in the normal position (not zoomed and rotated yet) but after ANY kind of rotation or zooming, dragging the stage will cause the stage to be re-positioned in a weird fashion (the offset is still correct though). How can I set position and offset correctly?

Comment: To make it work properly in current state will require some trigonometry to fix dragging after rotation. What I'd suggest is to use different layers for different actions - parent window with width/height equal to container always rotateable with offset in the center and dragging/scaling nested element (with `draggable` option without any calculations). So in any dragged state the offset of the parent will be same in the same location, but it will show different part of the nested image.

Comment: There may be some problems with scaling, though, as it also needs offset. I'd play with scaling on the same layer as rotation then.

Comment: By parent window, do you mean the stage or a new layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your initial issue below.
Note that I put a circle and a tooltip as well to a single layer to be able to drag them as a single one. Also, it should be added after `map` to have binding work.

```
import Konva from 'konva'
import map from './../resources/unpar.svg'

const width = window.innerWidth
const height = window.innerHeight

// scale is temp
let stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'canvas',
  width,
  height,
  offset: {
    x: width / 2,
    y: height / 2
  },
  x: width / 2,
  y: height / 2
})

let layer = new Konva.Layer({draggable: true})

let testCircle = new Konva.Circle({
  x: 633,
  y: 590,
  radius: 10,
  fill: 'white',
  stroke: 'black'
})

testCircle.on('mousemove', function () {
  tooltip.position({
    x: testCircle.x() - 90,
    y: testCircle.y() - 50
  })
  tooltip.text('Pintu Depan Gedung 10')
  tooltip.show()
  layer.batchDraw()
})

testCircle.on('mouseout', function () {
  tooltip.hide()
  layer.draw()
})

var tooltip = new Konva.Text({
  text: '',
  fontFamily: 'Calibri',
  fontSize: 18,
  padding: 5,
  textFill: 'white',
  fill: 'black',
  alpha: 0.75,
  visible: false
})

let imageObj = new Image()

imageObj.onload = function () {
  const map = new Konva.Image({
    image: imageObj,
  })

  layer.add(map)
  layer.add(testCircle)
  layer.add(tooltip)
  stage.add(layer)
}

imageObj.src = map

export default stage
```

Comment: I know this works, but is it possible to do it without lumping all object on single layer?

Comment: @CristopherNamchee Theoretically yes, but I am not sure how at the moment as it requires some research. If you could add one layer to another it would be quite simple, but there are a lot of restrictions of types which could include only certain types of containers/nodes.